# Value of the integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \log|re^{it}-\zeta| dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms

I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log|re^{it}-\zeta| dt$$
for $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$.

My approach so far has been to first assume $r\leq\zeta$, since this implies the integrand is the real part of a holomorphic branch of the logarithm, hence harmonic, which gives
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log|re^{it}-\zeta| dt = \log|\zeta| $$

For the case $r > \zeta$ I would like to conclude
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log|re^{it}-\zeta| dt =
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log|re^{it}| dt = \log r $$
but I don't quite see why the first equality in this equation should be true. Any help and hints are appreciated! :)

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\;r\le|\zeta|\;$ ? Because there is no linear order like that in the complex numbers...

Comment: You are using the mean value theorem for holomorphic functions $\displaystyle f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{it})dt$ where the integral is the mean value of $f$ around $z_0$ with radius $r$.

Comment: @DonAntonio That's what I thought, but the case where $r\leq |\zeta|$ is not the problem, as I have dealt with it already (see above).

Comment: @user90369 Thanks, but is my function holomorphic here (or maybe more precisely, the real part of a holomorphic function) ? I don't believe there is a holomorphic branch of the logarithm as I am integrating on the boundary of a disk that contains zeros.

Comment: @Mads Friis : Sorry to answer too late. *DonAntonio* has answered very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so we have the case $\;r>|\zeta|\;$ , but then

$$|re^{it}-\zeta|=|\overline{re^{it}-\zeta}|=|re^{-it}-\overline\zeta|=\frac{|r-\zeta e^{it}|}{|e^{it}|}=|r-\zeta e^{it}|$$

and we can apply the mean value theorem  $\;|r-\overline\zeta z |=|\overline\zeta e^{it}+(-r)|\;$ , and we have the mean value of this function of $\;r\;$ around the canonical circle of radius $\;|\zeta|\;$ :

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|r-\overline\zeta e^{ir}|dz=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\log|\overline\zeta e^{ir}+(-r)|dz=\log|(-r)|=\log r$$